# Bulk Printing in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, printing, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have a report using cascading parameters and sub-reports in SSRS.

I am able to print the report correctly for single student but when I select multiple ids I see that the data gets mixed up in the sub-reports.

I made sure I am using row grouping for studentID in all my sub-reports.

Any idea if I am missing anything?

Comment: Can you share an example of how `data get's mixed up` and what your expected output is?

Comment: It may have to do with the way you're passing parameters to the subreport. Confirm that each one is getting the correct student ID.